# Why header is bigger as height size as show in image?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to make grid view in Ionic. I am able to make grid view but I am facing some css issue .

- First my header height is too large as compared to image why? I need to reduce the height of the header or title of table.
- I am able to to give `margin-left: 5%`. It's working but if is `margin-right: 5%` is not working. Why?
- How to give different colour of alternate row?
- How to give colour separate line as show in image. To separate the column they use line:

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/FqL7g2w5yLEREopY4B10?p=preview

```
.mrginrightleft {
   margin-left: 5%; 
   margin-right: 5%;
}
.brd {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: For alternate rows consider :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even) selectors for tr of your table. This is using CSS3.

Comment: @fsacer could you use plunker

Comment: any update of this Queston

Comment: Ask only one question per question, please.

Comment: @isherwood - Why only ask 1 question? It would be a waste of time to create a post for all XX number of questions regarding the same code

Comment: Because the value of the question to the community is diminished when a bunch of separate questions are listed under a single question title, and where the tags don't accurately reflect the nature of the individual questions.

Comment: Also, users may not be able to answer all questions, reducing participation (note the low response rate to what are, individually, fairly simple questions) and reducing clarity in the answers that are provided, which makes upvoting and acceptance murky as well. It's just not a good way to use SO. There are cases where a followup or a related question should be included with the primary question. That's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the width on your `.row` your margin-right works

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  /* width: 100%; */
```

As for your alternate row color, @fsacer was correct to use `nth:child(odd) / (even);`, except your header row has the same classes. You could make it easier and add different class names to the "table rows" and exclude the header as so:

```
      <div class="row gray-20 mrginrightleft">
        <div class="col col-center " ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{checked: true}"><i class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-click="sortdata()"></i><strong>{{d.label}}</strong></div>
        <div class="col col-10 text-center ">
          <button class=" button-icon icon ion-gear-b" ng-click="openPopover($event)"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- added class "table-row" -->
      <div class="row mrginrightleft table-row" ng-repeat="column in displayData | filter: query">
        <div class="col col-center brd" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="data[$index].checked && data[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
        <div class="col col-10 text-center brd">
        </div>
      </div>

.scroll > .table-row:nth-child(odd) > div {
     background-color: red;
}

.scroll > .table-row:nth-child(even) > div {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

or make it harder:  (didn't test below - might have to play w/ the (2n+2) part)

```
.scroll > div.row.mrginrightleft:nth-child(2n+2) > div {
     background-color: red;
}

.scroll > div.row.mrginrightleft:nth-child(even) > div {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: could you please send plunker

Comment: just plug in what I have down into plunker. I don't know how to use that thing